# converting to PDO, problems

Tags: php, pdo

So I am working on converting an old tutorial I did a while back from `mySQL` to `PDO`. This way I can better understand the concepts. I seem to of run into a wall however. The following function is giving me an error

```
function user_data($user_id, $db) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`'; // !! LINE 12
        try {           
            $sql = sprintf('SELECT %s FROM members WHERE id = ?', $fields);         
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array($user_id));
            $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);         
            return $data;           
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

this is where I am calling the function

```
<?php 
session_start();
require 'database/connect_db.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

if (signedIn() === true) {
    $session_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_id, $db, 'email', 'password', 'role', 'name', 'company', 'title', 'phone', 'address', 'city', 'zip', 'state', 'ext', 'pic');
    echo $user_data['name'];
}

?>
```

this is my error

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\functions\users.php on line 12
```

So more specifically this line as commented on in the function above

```
$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
```

I don't see why this line is the causing this error. I also have no idea how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think `unset($func_get_args[0]);` should be `unset($func_get_args[1]);`. You're `unset`ting the $user_id instead of the $db

Comment: @Mike you were correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

func_get_args() returns *all* the arguments of the function.  You unset() the 0th element, but you have *two* elements you need to remove from the start of the args.  I show an example below of using array_slice() to start with element 2.

Also, your function has a glaring SQL injection vulnerability, interpolating the list of column names directly into your SQL select-list.  You should allowlist the input against a list of all the columns of your users table, to make sure the input doesn't contain something you don't expect.

```
function user_data($user_id, PDO $db) {
    // hardcoded list of the columns in the users table; use this as an allowlist
    $all_users_columns = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', /* etc. */);

    $columns = array_intersect(array_slice(func_get_args(), 2),
                               $all_users_columns);

    if($columns) {
        $column_list = implode(",", 
            array_map(function($col) { return "`$col`"; }, $columns));
        try {           
            $sql = sprintf('select %s from users where user_id = ?', $column_list);          
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array((int)$userid));
            $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);         
            return $data;           
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: + 1 thank you for pointing the vulnerability out. I had not thought of that

Comment: Anonymous downvoter: can you explain your objection to this answer?  Perhaps I can improve it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when you use `func_get_args` it is trying to format your `$db` argument in to a string.

I reworked your code a little to instead pass an array for the 3rd argument

```
function user_data($user_id, $db, $select = array()) {
    if (count($select)) $fields = "`".implode('`, `', $select)."`";
    else $fields = "*";

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT {$fields} FROM members WHERE id=?");              
        $stmt->execute(array($user_id));
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The way you would call this function now is like this:

```
$user_array = array('email', 'password', 'role', 'name', 'company', 'title', 'phone', 'address', 'city', 'zip', 'state', 'ext', 'pic');
$user_data = user_data($session_id, $db, $user_array);
```

Hopefully this works for your liking!

Comment: what worries me is that you corrected my query to what it should be. In the example I had `FROM users` and my table is in fact `members`. That is creepy

Comment: I started working on your previous question that got deleted I guess and had the code still saved.  Haha maybe a little creepy.

Comment: will do buddy, just checking it out now. At first you didn't bind the parameter for the `?`

Comment: it works! thanks. I hope you understand me giving Bill Karwin the accepted answer though. It is without a doubt the most complete answer and it goes beyond the scope of what I needed

Comment: When you put the array `array($user_id)` inside of `$stmt->execute()` as an argument, you don't need to bind the parameter.  It does it automatically.

Comment: @i_me_mine It's alright, thought I just provide a way to optimize the code.

Comment: It should help many other people, I've seen about 100 posts on here about this tutorial and converting it to PDO

Answer (score 2):

Your last arguemnt of function is PDO, you must remove it from field list with [array_pop](http://php.net/array_pop).

```
function user_data($user_id, $db) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    array_pop($func_get_args);        //<----------------------- line added

    if($func_num_args > 1) {
    // unset($func_get_args[0]);      // <---------------------- line commented
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`'; // !! LINE 12
        try {           
            $sql = sprintf('select %s from users where user_id = ?', $fields);          
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array($userid));
            $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);         
            return $data;           
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```